# Can Grafana cluster use cockroachDB as its metadata DB?

Tags: grafana, cockroachdb

I see that Grafana Cluster can use postgres or MySQL as its metadata DB.
Can it also use cockroachDB? 
(In general, I'm looking for an HA solution for Grafana, where the DB is also HA)

Thanks,
Moshe

Comment: CockroachDB is intended to work as a drop-in replacement for PostgresQL. Give it a shot!

Comment: user2720837 did you have any luck?

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in following along with this issue: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/8900

There are a couple of problems that prevent it from working out of the box right now. A big one right now is that CockroachDB only has experimental support for altering data types of columns, which Grafana uses.